# Type-hinting based on custom config file structure

Tags: python, pycharm, type-hinting

Is there a method in Python or PyCharm to produce attribute type hints for a class that dynamically loads the attributes from a file?

Consider the following `Settings` class:

```py
import re


class Settings:
    """
    This class loads a settings file and creates properties for each name in the file.
    The values are either strings or numbers.
    If the name starts with a star, the value is saved to self.cfg_dict to be used for wandb config.
    """

    def __init__(self, path):
        self.path = path
        self.cfg_dict = {}
        self.load_settings()

    def load_settings(self):
        with open(self.path, 'r') as file:
            for line in file:
                # if line is empty or starts with a comment, skip it
                if not line.strip() or line.strip().startswith('#'):
                    continue

                if '=' in line:
                    name, value = line.split('=')
                    name = name.strip()
                    value = value.strip()

                    # check if name has a star on the beginning and if so, save it to self.cfg_dict
                    if name.startswith('*'):
                        name = name[1:]
                        self.cfg_dict[name] = value.strip('"')
                    else:
                        # check if value is a number, either int or float
                        if re.match(r'^-?\d+$', value):
                            value = int(value)
                        elif re.match(r'^-?\d+\.\d+$', value):
                            value = float(value)
                        else:
                            value = value.strip('"')

                        setattr(self, name, value)
```

And a sample config:

```
var_a=5
var_b="Hello World"
```

Therefore, initializing `Settings` with the config file (`a = Settings('myconfig.cfg')`) would produce type hints for the new attributes: `a.var_a` and `a.var_b`. Is this possible to achieve in any shape or form, or am I best off just creating a dataclass and modify the parameters on the fly?

Answer (score 1):

You can generate a [.pyi stub file](https://peps.python.org/pep-0484/#stub-files) from your config. Stub files are read only by the language server to provide type checking and autocompletion. They aren't supposed to be executed. For example, you could generate something like this:

```py
# in a file called like the file you define `a` in, but with .pyi extension
class a:
    var_a: int
    var_b: str
```

This file would be seen by the language server and would be used to provide type-checking. Note that:

- It works only when you're importing `a` in another module, it doesn't work inside the module.
- You may need to restart the language server for it to recognize the file (subsequent changes should be recognized automatically).
- The stub file contents are allowed not to be proper Python code. It may contain nonexistent types and module imports. These would be simply ignored.

One of the ways you can generate a stub file is using the `ast` builtin module ([docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ast.html)). For example:

```py
import ast

a = type("a", (), {"test": 1})()

stub_class = ast.ClassDef("a", [], [], [], [])

for name in dir(a):
    attr = getattr(a, name)
    type_name = ast.Constant(type(attr).__qualname__)
    attr_name = ast.Name(name)
    stub_class.body.append(ast.AnnAssign(attr_name, type_name, simple=1))

with open(f"{__file__}i", "w") as f:
    f.write(ast.unparse(stub_class))
```

This code would create a stub file containing all the attributes of `a`, as seen at runtime. When importing `a`, the language server will see the `test` attribute, even though usually it won't see it.